# Sliding a button in android?

Tags: android, animation

I have this fragment in my application with a custom button on it, it's 50dp wide and its left margin is set to -25dp, so half of it is off screen. I'd like to animate it, so that at a certain event it moves for 50dp to the right and stays there.

I've tried this:

```
TranslateAnimation slide_anim=new TranslateAnimation(0,50,0,0);
slide_anim.setDuration(250);
mMovingButton.startAnimation(slide_anim);
```

but it moves it for 50 pixels and it does not stay there, how do I fix that?

Comment: slide_anim.setFillAfter(true); add this tag to your code.

Comment: this does seem to move it there, but the hitbox stays at the same position

Comment: That's because you are using the old animation system, you should use property animation. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code for it-

```
btnToSlide.animate().translationX(dpToPx(50,mContext)).setDuration(200)
        .setStartDelay(0).alpha(200);
```

To pass value in dp, Use dpToPx method-

```
    public static int dpToPx(int dp, Context context) {


DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics();
        int px = Math.round(dp
                * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
        return px;
    }
```